# Normal probability plot with percentile grid and axis

Tags: pgfplots

How can I make a normal probability plot with a percentile grid and y-axis as shown in figure? I've read the pgfplots documentation but i can't find anything useful.

[image: Normplot]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Related: [Weibull plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78074/weibull-plot-with-arbitrary-y-axis-scale)

Comment: With Jakes excellent solution and this question you should be able to generate your plot: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107423/erf-function-in-latex