# pgfplots: y-axis of a normal probability plot

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I'm trying to recreate the following normal probability plot in pgfplots without using R.

[image]

I already have the right data (percent, standardized effect). The only thing I struggle with is scaling the y-axis correctly. This is what I have so far:
[image]

The green plot should be linear when the axis is scaled correctly. I think `y coord trafo` should do the trick, but I can't get it right. (Compare the two images above.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    height=10cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    xmin=-6,
    ymax=99,
    ymin=1,
    xmax=7.5,
    ytick={1,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,95,99}
    ]

\addplot[Maroon,only marks] coordinates {
        (-5.444,4.54)
        (-4.166,11.039)
        (-2.662,17.5325)
        (-1.1622,24.026)
        (2.24,82.46) 
        (2.96,88.96) 
        (6.776,95.45)         
};

\addplot[black,only marks] coordinates {
        (-1.1622,24.026)
        (-0.865,30.52)
        (0.0677,37.013)
        (0.1106,43.50)
        (0.325,50)
        (0.520,56.49)
        (0.667,62.98)
        (0.88,69.48)
        (1.317,75.97) 
};

\addplot[green,smooth] coordinates {
        (-2.3,1)
        (-1.25,10)
        (-0.625,30)
        (-0.3125,40)
        (0,50)
        (0.3125,60)
        (0.625,70)
        (1.25,90)
        (2.3,99)
};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have already read these posts:

- [Normal probability plot with percentile grid and axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147257/normal-probability-plot-with-percentile-grid-and-axis)
- [pgfplots custom axis scaling function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114778/pgfplots-custom-axis-scaling-function)
- [weibull plot with arbitrary y axis scale](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78074/weibull-plot-with-arbitrary-y-axis-scale)
- [Erf function in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107423/erf-function-in-latex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. **MAJOR UPDATE**: Some of the things I said previously were not entirely correct, sorry for that. Here comes a revised answer. I have punched in [approximations of the `erf` function and its inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions), and using these I can make the line almost straight. You may have to adjust the `\Conv` parameter a bit, though.

[image]

The following code has a lot of explanation in it. It also has cross checks that the `erf` and the transformations using them work.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={a=0.140002;
myerf(\x)=sign(\x)*sqrt(1-exp(-\x*\x*(((4/pi)+a*\x*\x)/(1+a*\x*\x))));
myinverf(\x)=sign(\x)*sqrt(sqrt((((2/(pi*a))+0.5*ln(1-\x*\x)))^2-ln(1-\x*\x)/a)
-((2/(pi*a))+ln(1-\x*\x)/2));
myinvtrafo(\x,\y)=50*myerf(\y*(\x-50)/50)+50);
mytrafo(\x,\y)=(50/\y)*myinverf((\x-50)/50)+50;
}}

The $\erf$ function and its inverse are from
\begin{quote}
\verb|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Approximation_with_elementary_functions|.
\end{quote}
In Figure~\ref{fig:erf} it is shown that they look as they should, and are also
inverse to each other.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    height=10cm,smooth,samples=51,
   legend entries={$\erf$,$\erf^{-1}$,$\erf^{-1}\circ
   \erf$},
   ]
 \addplot[red,domain=-3:3] {myerf(x)};  
 \addplot[blue,domain=-0.99:0.99] {myinverf(x)};  
 \addplot[green!60!black,domain=-3:3] {myinverf(myerf(x))};  
\end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$\erf$ and $\erf^{-1}$. Cross check that 
$\erf^{-1}\circ\erf$ is the identity.}
\label{fig:erf}
\end{figure}


\pgfmathsetmacro{\Conv}{0.5}

The transformations you are interested in should map $]0,100[$ to $]0,100[$,
where 0 corresponds to $\erf(x\to-\infty)=-1$ and 100 to $\erf(x\to\infty)=1$. 
They are hence of the form
\begin{align}
 t(x,y)~&=~ 50\cdot \erf\left(y\cdot\frac{x-50}{50}\right)+50\;,\\
 t^{-1}(x,y)~&=~\frac{50}{y}\cdot \erf^{-1}\left(\frac{x-50}{50}\right)+50\;,
\end{align}
where $y>0$ is a parameter. These transformations are plotted for $y=\Conv$ in
Figure~\ref{fig:t}.
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    height=10cm,smooth,samples=51,
   legend entries={$t$,$t^{-1}$,$t\circ t^{-1}$},
   ]
 \addplot[red,domain=0:100] {mytrafo(x,\Conv)};  
 \addplot[blue,domain=0:100] {myinvtrafo(x,\Conv)};  
 \addplot[green!60!black,domain=1:99] {myinvtrafo(mytrafo(x,\Conv),\Conv)};  
\end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$t$ and $t^{-1}$.}
\label{fig:t}
\end{figure}

These transformations can then be feed into your plot
(Figure~\ref{fig:yourplot}). I was, however, unable to
find a value of $y$ that makes the green line precisely straight. However, it is
almost straight. You may have to play a bit.

\begin{figure}[b]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{round(\tick)}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},
    height=10cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    xmin=-6,
    ymax=99,
    ymin=1,
    xmax=7.5,
    ymax=99,
    ytick={1,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,95,99},
    y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{mytrafo(#1,\Conv)},
    y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{myinvtrafo(#1,\Conv)},
    ]

\addplot[Maroon,only marks] coordinates {
        (-5.444,4.54)
        (-4.166,11.039)
        (-2.662,17.5325)
        (-1.1622,24.026)
        (2.24,82.46) 
        (2.96,88.96) 
        (6.776,95.45)         
};

\addplot[black,only marks] coordinates {
        (-1.1622,24.026)
        (-0.865,30.52)
        (0.0677,37.013)
        (0.1106,43.50)
        (0.325,50)
        (0.520,56.49)
        (0.667,62.98)
        (0.88,69.48)
        (1.317,75.97) 
};

\addplot[green,smooth] coordinates {
        (-2.3,1)
        (-1.25,10)
        (-0.625,30)
        (-0.3125,40)
        (0,50)
        (0.3125,60)
        (0.625,70)
        (1.25,90)
        (2.3,99)
};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:yourplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! the data of the green plot is indeed aproximated so i think your answer is entirely correct.